# send var into php file from javascript

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, web, yii2

it try to use Ajax in php.
is write a code and at the end send a var "Id" into a php file :

```
xmlhttp.open("GET", "details.php?q="+Id,true);
```

there is no problem in the code , details.php run but details.php give me this Error :  Notice: Undefined index: Id in C:\wamp64\www\adv3\advanced\frontend\web\details.php on line 2

and here it is my seconde line in details.php :

```
<?php
$q = $_GET['Id'];
```

what is the problem ? i send Id well .

Comment: You are passing query string as q. So use $q = $_GET['q']; instead of Id.

Answer (score 2):

You get an error because the querystring parameter you are sending up is `q`, not `Id`.

```
xmlhttp.open("GET", "details.php?q="+Id,true);  
                                 ^^
```

so your PHP should be

```
$q = $_GET['q'];
```

Answer (score -1):

Which browser are you on? Anyways; you could use JQuery to make your Life a lot easier.

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    (function($) {
        $(document).ready(function(){
            $.ajax({
                url     : "details.php",
                type    : "GET",
                data    : {"Id" : Id },
                success: function (data, textStatus, jqXHR){
                },

                error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                    console.log('The following error occurred: ' + textStatus, errorThrown);
                }
            });
        });
    })(jQuery);
</script>
```